# Fail to install Axis2 1.8.2 eclipse plugins

Tags: apache-axis

I've downloaded Apache Axis2 1.8.2 eclipse plugins from
https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html :

axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.8.2-dist.zip
axis2.eclipse.service.plugin-1.8.2-dist.zip

The zip files were unpacked and both of them contains the same named jar files in the plugins directory

${bundle-symbolic-name}_${bundle-version}.jar

I copied the jar file into the eclipse/dropins dir but no plugin was installed.

What's going wrong with it ?
Are the download resources corrupted ?

Thank you.

Regards,

Albert.